# Rails redirect alters url preventing from loading images

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I made a log in controller and view configuration that on successful log-in adds a session variable. When the controller returns to the client side javascript I use JQuery to reload the page, where the initial controller checks for the session variable. If the variable exists then I redirect to the main page.

loggedIn = session[:loggedIn]

```
if(loggedIn == true)
    #redirect_to :controller => 'overview', :action => 'homepage'
    redirect_to 'overview/homepage'
else
    render 'login'
end
```

All of this works well accept for when the main page tries to load images via javascript to stick into google maps, it defaults to the new URL as it's origin. prior to the addition of the login screen the url would be this to find the image:

```
    http://localhost:3000/images/image.png
```

however after the redirect it tries to find the image in a url as follows

```
    http://localhost:3000/overview/images/image.png
```

This clearly fails when no such file directory exists. This also messed up some of my calls to the server but I worked around them with a few changes to my routes files.

This is the javascript code referencing the image

```
    var someImage = {
            url: '/images/image.png', 
            size: new google.maps.Size(40,40), 
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(20,20)
         }
```

How do I keep the url from being changed, having 'overview' added to part of my image directory?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Between my routes file and trial and error attempts I had gotten some code jumbled.

apparently this

```
    redirect_to :controller => 'overview', :action => 'homepage'
```

changes the root in the url.

simply keeping the

```
    redirect_to '/overview/homepage'
```

and the

```
    get 'overview/homepage'
```

in the routes file is the correct redirect.